# How to call function inside the cshtml file by using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I create a method to clear the `Session` value. But I don't know how to call that method in jQuery. Like this:

in Index.cshtml:

```
@functions{
    public void ClearSession(){
        Session["Value"] = null;
    }
}
```

and in jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// this.ClearSession() won't work here...
});
</script>
```

Can you help me?

p/s: I'm using MVC 5.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between _client-side_ code and _server-side_ code. You need AJAX.

Comment: Your first function is in C# (ie. server-side), the second is in JavaScript (ie. client-side). They cannot communicate directly in a page like this. You would need to make an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes simple solution using `AJAX GET`. Let your Server Side Controller Action be, I created a controller with name `HomeController`.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ClearSession()
{
    Session["Value"] = null;
    return Json(true);
}
```

And your JQuery should be as shown below.

**NOTE:** If you want, the same Ajax call can be made in `$(document).ready(fn)` as well.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/home/ClearSession",
                success: function (data) { alert(data); },
                failure: function (errMsg) {
                  alert(errMsg);
                }
           });
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="button" value="Click" id="btnSubmit" />
```

Then when you click the button it will hit the controller action as shown below -

[image]